# VBA - SQL - Include records with zero count

Tags: sql, vba

I'm new to SQL fiddling with JOINS & failing to get the outcome. Any help would be truly appreciated.

### Requirement

I've got a table, DATA1 & a copy of it called DATA2. The columns in it are EMPID,JOINING_DATE,DESIGNATION,COMMENTS,GENDER,DEPARTMENT

I've got VB code which selects data from the excel sheet containing the above 2 sheets using ADO. When I run a query say, get me the count of number of employees who joined IT department every month between 01/2011 & 03/2011, I expect to see result similar to the below

```
01/2011 0
02/2011 1
03/2011 0
```

### Sample Data

I've created sample data below

```
1|01/2011|AAA|DG1|asdasdasd|Male|Sales
2|01/2011|BBB|DG1|asdasdasd|Female|Networking
3|02/2011|AAA|DG7|asdasdasd|Male|Sales
4|02/2011|AAA|DG5|asdasdasd|Female|IT
5|03/2011|AAA|DG1|asdasdasd|Male|MArketing
```

Please can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have someone who started in each month:

```
select year(joining_date), month(joining_date),
       sum(case when department = 'IT' then 1 else 0 end)
from sample 
group by year(joining_date), month(joining_date)
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon,Thanks for this. With ADO, "when" doesn't work. I've looked around for workarounds but can't get anything that works. Is there an alternate for this please?

Comment: What database are you using?